# BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE vs. SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE in WordPress Multisite?

Tags: multisite, constants

I've been trying to figure out why we have the constants `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` and `SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE` *(vs. hardcoding them to be equal to `1`)*, what exactly the differences are, and when either of them will not equal 1?

Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I addressed a similar question on StackOverflow [last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184146/wordpress-difference-between-site-id-and-blog-id/4189358#4189358).

In MultiSite, "blog" is a reference to an individual website.  "Site" is a reference to a network of "blogs."  In the future, there's the likelihood that WordPress will be able to power multiple networks ("site"s) in addition to its current state of multiple "blog"s.

---

**Update**

I've done some more digging, and discovered a plug-in that easily allows you to split your multi-site installation into a multi-network one: [WP Multi Network](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multi-network/).

Comment: So currently *"site"* is only ever '1'?  BTW, Google failed me on finding that question via SO.

Comment: the future is now - multiple networks are possible and have been ever since this was put in place.

Comment: Possible, yes.  Well-understood, well-documented, and well-known, no.

Comment: @andrea_r: can you share some links about that multi network feature?

Comment: @hakre: Also, see my update linking to a multi-network plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

@hakre - see the updated plugin link above. Previously, we called this multisite in wpmu. ;) that plugin was based on an old plugin for wpmu called multi-site.

We had one as well here: http://wpmututorials.com/simple-multi-site-plugin-e-book/

Actually, my wpmututorials.com site is a mapped domain in a multisite install, and my personal domain atypicalife.net is another network inside the same installation.

So yeah - I'm already using this feature and have been for a while. I talked about this in WC NYC in 2009.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still unclear on use-cases for a Network?  What value would 3 sites with 3 blogs each have over a WordPress multisite install that has just 1 site but 9 blogs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The URLs. :) If I wanted multiple mapped domains with their own sub-blogs, I'd need separate installs, or use multiple networks.