# How can I append blog_id to ... echo [functions-defined-constant]?

Tags: multisite, functions, constants

I use 'constants' a lot. I set them in functions.php like `define('mytheme_town', 'Orlando');` and then call them into the theme `<?php echo mytheme_town ; ?>`.

It's simple and easy.  But I need them to be site-specific (for multisite) so I thought it might be possible to append the current blog_id to the theme call and declare constants for each MultiSite in functions.php? I don't know how to code that, but what I'm trying to achieve in the theme file this ... `<?php echo [current_blog]_mytheme_town ; ?>` .....

For example

**In functions.php**
// set constants for all multisites that use this theme

// awebsite.org : site_id=1
define('1_mytheme_town', 'Orlando');
define('1_mytheme_subject', 'food');
define('1_mytheme_p1', 'This is the first paragraph text');

//  adifferentsite.com: site_id=2
define('2_mytheme_town', 'New York');
define('2_mytheme_subject', 'wine');
define('2_mytheme_p1', 'This is the first paragraph text');

// anothersite.net : site_id=3 
define('3_mytheme_town', 'LA');
define('3_mytheme_subject', 'Donuts');
define('3_mytheme_p1', 'This is the first paragraph text');

**In theme files**
Call the constants using the current blog_id like so ...

`<?php echo [current_blog]_mytheme_town ; ?>`
`<?php echo [current_blog]_mytheme_subject ; ?>`
`<?php echo [current_blog]_mytheme_p1 ; ?>`

I have been trying all day, but I'm just guessing and I don't really know what I am doing. Everything I have tried works, but it simply echos out text of the code

> 1_mytheme_town

and not the constant that is defined in functions.php.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the blog ID you are on by `global $blog_id;` and then you can use that how you want it to work.

Comment: I've not been able to append `global $blog_id;` to the defined function and therefore echo out [blog_id]_[functions_defined_text] @Ashfame. I can only get it to echo out the actual blog_id # followed by the template function call. I tried this `global $blog_id; echo $blog_id; echo _mytheme_town;` but it simple echos out 
- 1_mytheme_town
- 2_mytheme_town
- 3_mytheme_town

Can you give a code demo of your technique?

Comment: First construct the name into a variable and then use variable of a variable. `$name=$blog_id.'_my_theme_town; echo $$name;`

Answer (score 2):

Using constants in the way you are doing is very much *not* the way a good WordPress programmer would code.  Constants are very inflexible and just not how things are typically done in WordPress.

Assuming that when you refer to *"site"* you really mean *"blog"* in **[WordPress' Multisite vernacular](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/blog-id-current-site-vs-site-id-current-site-in-wordpress-multisite)** *(yes, I think the terminology is strange but it is what it is)* then why not use `get_blog_option()` and `update_blog_option()` along with `get_site_option()` and `update_site_option()`? *(this code goes in your main blog's theme's `functions.php` file, or in a `.php` file of a [**"must use" plugin**](http://wpmututorials.com/basics/must-use-plugins-and-3-0/) you might be developing):*

```
add_action('init','yoursite_init');
function yoursite_init() {
  if (!get_site_option('town_subject_p1_initialized')) {
    
    update_blog_option(1,'town','Orlando');
    update_blog_option(1,'subject','food');
    update_blog_option(1,'p1','This is the first paragraph text');
    
    update_blog_option(2,'town','New York');
    update_blog_option(2,'subject','wine');
    update_blog_option(2,'p1','This is the first paragraph text');
    
    update_blog_option(3,'town','LA');
    update_blog_option(3,'subject','donuts');
    update_blog_option(3,'p1','This is the first paragraph text');
  
    update_site_option('town_subject_p1_initialized',true);
  
  }
}
```

Then to access within your theme use the following code:

```
<?php echo get_blog_option($blog_id,'town'); ?>
<?php echo get_blog_option($blog_id,'subject'); ?>
<?php echo get_blog_option($blog_id,'p1'); ?>
```

This is a lot more *"WordPress-like"* and you'll find it's both a lot more flexible and someone else who knows WordPress is a lot more likely to actually understand the code you leave behind.

### UPDATE

Based on comments I'm going to suggest a different approach for initialization.  Rather than have the programmer constantly editing the .PHP file every time he wants to add a new site the site meta should be added using the `'wpmu_new_blog'` hook which you can see here:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog','getsunrise_wpmu_new_blog');
function getsunrise_wpmu_new_blog( $blog_id ) {
  update_blog_option( $blog_id,'town','Pending...');
  update_blog_option( $blog_id,'subject','Pending...');
  update_blog_option( $blog_id,'p1','Pending...');
}
```

Then the site admin can edit the site meta at this URL `/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id={$site_ID}` *(replacing {$site_ID} with the new site #, of course.)* For example:

[image: Screenshot of editing blog-specific settings in WordPress Multisite]

Scroll down to the bottom of that page and then you see the three (3) new site meta values:

[image: Screenshot of editing blog-specific additional site meta in WordPress Multisite]

This is a ***much*** better way that using constants and editing the `.php` file.  Your clients won't know, but subconsciously they will thank you for not causing them future headaches.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many sites I could add in this manner @MikeSchinkel? Also, I added the update/gets for one site to test your code, and it worked perfectly. I then proceeded to add more, but the additional sites are not working. No cache plugins are activate; do I need to "reset"/flush something?

Comment: I added @MikeSchinkle's code for update_blog_option to functions for blog 1 to test it, and it worked perfectly. So I then I added update_blog_option to the same add_action call in functions.php for the additional blogs (2 and 3) but they don't work?

I've tried re-saving the permalinks (which I read helps force-refresh something to do with functions.php).

Once an add_action init has been added, can it be edited?

Comment: @Thao - Are your different sites using the same theme?

Comment: They are @MikeSchinkel. Which is why I'm trying to use this sort of method (to streamline my workload). Not *every* blog in the Network is using the same theme, but every blog referenced by update_blog_option is.

It's been suggested to me that once the get_site_option has been initialized the first time, that the if statement will no longer be true `if (!get_site_option('title_desc_p1_city_url_initialized'))` therefore any extra info I add will not be updated.

So I tried commenting out the if statement, but have had no joy with that either.

Comment: That's assuming when you refer to "site" @MikeSchinkel you really mean "blog" in WordPress' Multisite vernacular (yes, I think the terminology is strange but it is what it is). #laughing

Comment: @Thao - I just tested it again and it and it works fine on a multisite. Are you sure you are associating the correct blog_id numbers with the correct blog? Have you tried adding a `<?php echo $blog_id; ?>` to your theme to make sure you are associating the correct number? Also try putting the `update_blog_option()` code into a file in the *"Must Use"* plugins directory, maybe `/wp-content/mu-plugins/site-blog-options.php`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I was already printing out the blog_id, so these are correct.

I stripped everything out and started again. All was well for the first few edits, but now subsequent updates (editing the paragraph text for example) do not "update".

I also tested this with Twenty Ten theme to ensure it's not a problem with the theme I'm using, but had the same issue. ***The initial initialization does update, as do the first few edits, but after that they do not***.

Could it be a database cache issue? I do not have any Cache plugins installed.

Any chance you can test this with several edits?

Comment: @Thao - Do you understand what my code is doing so you can modify it for your changing requirements, or are you just copying and pasting what I provided? I'm only asking to understand why this is a struggle; it should be really simple? Also, I don't understand what you mean by an *"edit"*; do you keep editing the source code? What are you editing? If you are continuing toeditthe source code you are approaching the problem wrong. You should only use this technique if you writing the code once. Otherwise use a Custom Post Type and Custom Fields.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Thanks for your time on this.

I understand the concept, but not the exacts of the code. By edit I mean if I add another blog tomorrow (id=4) and want to use this theme I will add an additional block of update_blog_option's to suit. Or if I want to modify the text of id=2,  'p1' from 'This is the first paragraph text' to 'This is a paragraph'. I know this functions method (or the 'constants' I initially asked about) are not the "most proper method" of doing things, but I have 40 x 1 page blogs using the same theme. Editing via a single file V's 40 WP Admin entires is a dream.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel ***update*** I have reverted back to my original 'constants' method (as incorrect as it is). Thanks for your help anyway. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Thao - Are you using this approach for your own blog? If so, okay. Are you doing it for a client or someone else? If so, you really need to use a more standard approach otherwise you are doing a disservice to your client for when they need to get someone else to maintain the site. Go to `/wp-admin/ms-sites.php?action=editblog&id=1` on your site, look at the bottom left. It's here where you should edit those values, NOT in the `.php` file itself. This is a CMS, you shouldn't have to edit `.php` files when you want to make a content change.

Comment: @Thao - Please see my answer updates.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Yes they are all my sites. Which is why I am trying to streamline my workloads. I appreciate your help on this, and your education along the way (it's always great learning new things in the process of). I don't totally agree with "in a CMS, should edit content not .php files": you have to consider the scope of how WordPress (and particularly MultiSite) is being used now. And in my case, it's 10,000 x more work to edit 50 blogs inside WP Admin than a single .php file. It's not "proper" I know, but it's far more practical. Thanks again Mike!

Comment: @Thao - Well, as long as this is for your sites and you are not distributing in plugins or themes then do whatever works for you.